# Emacs/AUCTeX: run command on file that is not currently open

Tags: emacs, latex, lisp, auctex

I edit my LaTeX files in Emacs using AUCTeX. To compile, I press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, which will run `pdflatex root`, if `root.tex` is the file displayed in the current buffer.

But what if I want it to run `pdflatex` on a file that is not displayed in the current buffer?

For example, I am editing an included `.tex` file, `chapter2.tex`, and press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>. The command I want it to run is still `pdflatex root`, since `chapter2.tex` is just included in `root.tex`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you create a new file AUCTeX will ask you about the "master" document for it. If you define a master, <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> will compile the master instead of the currently open file.

AUCTeX keeps track of this by adding a footer with the information it needs. Assuming you have a master document `index.tex`, the footer would look like this:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "index"
%%% End:
```

Comment: The local variable route has the disadvantage of requiring you to kill the buffer and reopen it before the variable is set (maybe there's a smarter way to do it?). The first time you open the file, you can also do `M-x TeX-master-file-ask`.

Comment: @ChrisConway The smarter way is `M-x normal-mode`.

Answer (score 8):

C-c _ creates this footer automatically

Comment: ON my system `C-C _` is bound to `TeX-master-file-ask`, but it doesn't create the local variable footer.

Comment: It should create after you define the master file.
But it doesn't work if the footer is already defined